# jQuery .on accumulates click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have a component which manages a view that contains articles with games and to preventing overload of memory and spend time using a for with every article if it is open on a new window or reloads the current page (with a checkbox), I made this code, when the user clicks on an article(each one has the class "flashgame"), depending of user's choice it will go to a game and, or reload the current page, or, open in another window and play the game.

this is my code:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.flashgame', function () {
  console.log(this);
  let denom = jQuery(this).find('.urlGame').data('denom');
  let val = jQuery(this).find('.urlGame').data('val');
  if (denom != "") {
    let gamear = denom.toString().split(',');
    let orderset: any[] = gamear;
    if (orderset.length > 1) {
      that.multidenoms = orderset.sort((a, b) => { return a - b; });
      that.gameId = val;
      console.log("modalflash is showing");
      that.modalflash.show();
    }
    else {
      that.goToFlash(val, gamear);
    }
  }
  else {
    that.goToFlash(val);
  }
});
```

and this is the article:

[image]

but for any reason when I made this change in the project, the page has been accumulate the number of clicks, for instance:

Hard reload and the number of "clicks" starts in zero, I go to another page and then go back, the click has incremented by one, an so on.

So, what should I do? Is there any workaround to prevent this "clicks" overload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I like to do is use .off before .on when rebinding event handlers.
So something like this:

```
jQuery(document).off('click', '.flashgame').on('click', '.flashgame', function () { ...
```